# Sql query match and against order by relevance using regex?

Tags: mysql

Hello I'm trying to make a query in sql using match and against to sort by relevance. I don't want to use the like query or the REGEXP because my index is a FULLTEXT and it'll run faster...

This is my query:

```
SELECT test.*, MATCH(books) AGAINST ('+\'book') as Relevance
FROM Books.test 
WHERE MATCH(books) AGAINST('+\'book' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY Relevance
```

And the result that I'm getting is:

```
id  books              relavance

2   book, folder, paper    '0.15835624933242798'

5  'book                  '0.15835624933242798'
```

The dataypes are:

id is an INT(11)
books LONGTEXT

And the indexes that I have:

```
key             type      unique   columns

idx_test_books  FULLTEXT  NO       books
```

I want to only retrieve the book with id 5: 'book

Comment: provide your dummy table structure

Comment: It's a little bit unclear which rows you want to find and which rows you don't want to find based on a given search string. Please edit your question to include more example data, the search string you use and the search result you want.

Comment: Ok I get it, there's no way I can get 'book returned. I tried to come up with a workaround thanks to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use FULLTEXT for a search for `'book`, the apostrophe will be ignored. The FULLTEXT index is [builds with words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html#innodb-fulltext-index-design).

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT *, MATCH(books) AGAINST('"book,.,.,.,$%$:;§$%:;§$%§$:$%"') AS relevance FROM Books ORDER BY relevance;
+----+---------------------+----------------------------+
| id | books               | relevance                  |
+----+---------------------+----------------------------+
|  1 | book, folder, paper | 0.000000001885928302414186 |
|  2 | 'book               | 0.000000001885928302414186 |
+----+---------------------+----------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> SELECT *, MATCH(books) AGAINST('"book,.,.,.,$%$:;§$%folder:;§$%§$:$%"') AS relevance FROM Books ORDER BY relevance;
+----+---------------------+--------------------+
| id | books               | relevance          |
+----+---------------------+--------------------+
|  2 | 'book               |                  0 |
|  1 | book, folder, paper | 0.0906190574169159 |
+----+---------------------+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> SELECT *, MATCH(books) AGAINST('"book folder"') AS relevance FROM Books ORDER BY relevance;
+----+---------------------+--------------------+
| id | books               | relevance          |
+----+---------------------+--------------------+
|  2 | 'book               |                  0 |
|  1 | book, folder, paper | 0.0906190574169159 |
+----+---------------------+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```